# Как установить GL4Java в Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java, opengl

Я новичок в Java. JAR файлы установил. Вот что получилось. Подскажите, куда .dll файлы библиотеки нужно вставить?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачиваете файлы GL4java.
`png.jar`, `gl4java.jar`, `gl4java-glutfonts.jar` и `gl4java-glffonts.jar` помещаете в папку `JAVA_HOME\lib\ext`.
Файлы dll необходимо разместить в `C:\Windows\System` или `C:\Windows\System32` в зависимости от версии Windows.
Далее необходимо установить разрешения для GL4java. Откройте в блокноте `JAVA_HOME\lib\security\java.policy` и добавьте туда строку

```
grant codeBase "file:${java.home}/lib/ext/*" { permission java.security.AllPermission; }
```

[Источник](http://monkeyfighter.com/gl4java.html)

От себя добавлю, что возможно придется регистрировать dll файлы (а может и не придется). В командной строке надо набрать

```
regsvr32 “C:/Windows/System32/example.dll”
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это все я прочитал сразу же, и действовал по этой инструкции.
Но черт побери все это не поможет , если на стадии создания проекта в Eclipse  не указать "Use a project specific JRE" 
http://gyazo.com/63c7d949f83987beb768bb87f13556cb
Я указывал по привычке так ---->>>
http://gyazo.com/4dd749b01c1c189261b7737bb709ba31

Это жесть. Почему именно "Use a project specific JRE"?

Comment: Далее необходимо установить разрешения для GL4java. Откройте в блокноте JAVA_HOME\lib\security\java.policy и добавьте туда строку

у меня вот такая строчка  - grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
оставлять? или все же менять на 
grant codeBase "file:${java.home}/lib/ext/*" { permission java.security.AllPermission; }?

Comment: + так и не удается импортировать вот эту библиотеку - net.java.games.jogl.GL;
где ее взять?

Comment: Как я понимаю GL4java и JOGL это разные вещи.  
По установке [JOGL][1] смотрите по ссылке.
[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615899/where-can-i-download-jogl  
По поводу разрешений- главное, чтобы для папки с GL4java были установлены разрешения, а каким образом Вы укажете путь это не важно.